# Perl XML parser

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

I have an XML file that I am parsing using the [`XML::Parser`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Parser/Parser/Style/Tree.pm) Perl module. Code for parsing XML:

```
..........................................
$parser = XML::Parser->new(Style => 'Tree');
$my_map = $parser->parse($xml);
print Dumper($my_map->[1]) . "\n";
```

Result of the `print Dumper($my_map->[1])` statement:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {},
          0,
          '
            ',
          'lfs',
          [
            {
              'name' => 'ABC'
            },
            0,
            '
                 ',
            'FS',
            [
              {
                'status' => '1',
                'acc' => '/tmp',
                'kind' => 'ass'
              }
            ],
            0,
            '
            '
          ],
          0,
          '
            ',
          'lfs',
          [
            {
              'name' => 'BCG'
            },
            0,
            '
                 ',
            'FS',
            [
              {
                'status' => '1',
                'acc' => '/home/tmpspace/tmp1',
                'kind' => 'oops'
              }
            ],
            0,
            '
                 ',
            'FS',
            [
              {
                'status' => '1',
                'acc' => '/home/tmpspace/tmp2',
                'kind' => 'hops'
              }
            ],
            0,
            '
            '
          ],
          0,
          '
            ',
          'lfs',
          [
            {
              'name' => 'KMN'
            },
            0,
            '
                 ',
            'FS',
            [
              {
                'status' => '1',
                'acc' => '/misc/ib',
                'kind' => 'nops'
              }
            ],
            0,
            '
            '
          ],
          0,
          '
            ',
          'lfs',
          [
            {
              'name' => 'MAIN'
            },
            0,
            '
                 ',
            'FS',
            [
              {
                'status' => '1',
                'acc' => 'This is the string that I wanted.',
                'kind' => 'mount'
              }
            ],
            0,
            '
            '
          ],
          0,
          '
    '
        ];
```

From `$my_map->[1]`, I wanted to get `'acc' => 'This is the string that I wanted.'`. How do I fetch `'acc' => 'This is the string that I wanted.'` efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this, iterating each ARRAY level:

```
use strict; use warnings;

foreach my $first_level (@$VAR1) {
    if(ref $first_level eq "ARRAY") {
        foreach my $second_level (@{ $first_level }) {
            if(ref $second_level eq "ARRAY") {
                foreach my $third_level (@{ $second_level }) {
                    print $third_level->{acc}, "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: POST edited, better coding style, shorter and more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `XML::Parser`, I would suggest you look into using `XML::LibXML` instead and then use XPath notation to find particular elements in your XML (via the `findnodes()` method).

Doing this allows you to get at certain nodes in an XML document without the need to fully understand its complete structure (or, depend on the source XML being formatted in a particular manner).

XML::LibXML is [described here](https://bitbucket.org/shlomif/perl-xml-libxml), while you can get more info on [XPath notation here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree XML:LibXML is far better. But to use XML::Parser is a sort of compulsion. :(

Comment: Another possibility is to use `XML::Twig`. It's easier to use than `XML::Parser`, and it's pure perl, so installing or using it is probably easier than `XML::LibXML`.

Comment: I can appreciate the argument about using a pure-perl solution if the underlying library is unlikely to be available... but, libxml2 is virtually ubiquitous; most modern Linux distros can't function without it.  And besides, it's wicked fast :D (and super powerful)